Whats the time complexity of this function?
I made this function to remove all duplicate elements from a linked list and I thought the complexity was O(n^2) although tabnine says that the inner for loop runs k times where k is the # of unique elements in the linked list, therefore k is a constant and the inner for loop only has a complexity O(1). Im not sure which one is correct, could someone explain it to me?
void remove_dupes(struct node * head){
    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL){return;
    }

    int *nums = malloc(1*sizeof(int));
    int k = 1; int max = 1;
    nums[0] = head->value; struct node *prev = head;
    head = head->next;

    while(head){ 
        int flag = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i<k;i++){ //runs k times where k is the # of unique elemnts in the list
            if (nums[i] == head->value){
                flag = 0;
            }
        }

        if(flag){
            k +=1;
            if(k>max){
                max = max*2;
                nums = realloc(nums,sizeof(int)*max);
            }
            nums[k-1]= head->value; prev = head; head = head->next;
        }
        else{
            prev->next = head->next; free(head); head= prev->next;
        }
    }
}


I suppose you are taking realloc as a constant-time operation. It is not. However, even given that, suppose the list is composed of n unique elements. In each iteration of the while, the inner loop will not find a duplicate, leaving flag as 1. Then the if will add the new value to nums and increment k. So the inner loop must run 1 time in the first iteration, 2 in the second, 3 in the third, and so on, a total of n•(n−1)/2 times. Do not use AI to analyze or write software.

Unless all lists to be used by this function have k unique values, then k is a variable (could be different for each list) as well as n (could be different for each list) and the time complexity should be O(n k ).

How can k be a constant? It's  the number of unique elements in the input, so it varies with the input.

alright so in conclusion, in the worst case k = n when there are no duplicates thus having 2 O(n) loops causing O(n^2)

Side note: If the list is sorted, the dup scan is O(n). Linked lists lend themselves well to a mergesort. If the original list can't be sorted, an extra next_sorted field could help. Works better with a doubly linked list. Or, an extra [temp] array could be created, sorted, and used to remove elements. Even with the extra overhead of creating the sorted list, it can still be faster than O(n^2).
